# jQuery Plugin/Widget Only Modifying Last Instantiated Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm fairly new to jQuery plugins so I think this is a relatively simple issue.

I've created a plugin to control an HTML calendar. I want to be able to have multiple calendars on the same page. Each calendar keeps track of its own data via the plugin.

When I have a single calendar on the page, it works great. However, as soon as more are added there are problems. The `settings` object (which stores all the calendar info) only gets updated for the last instantiated calendar. So when I click something to modify the first calendar, the `settings` object for the first calendar is not changed at all; only the second calendar's `settings` object is updated.

I think it's either an issue in how my plugin runs against the incoming jQuery objects or the way I'm using the `data()` method.

In my code below, when either of the 'change settings' listeners are fired, the `settings.listView` value is supposed to be changed. Then, when the `showSettings()` method is called it's supposed to use the updated value.

Here's a stripped down version of my plugin:

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        _init: function($el, options, config){

            var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.pluginName.defaults, options, config);

            $el.data("settings", settings);
            settings = $el.data("settings");
            this.$el = $el;

            var instance = this;


            // change settings
            $el.on("click", ".popup.settings li.calendar", function(){
                // do stuff...

                //settings.listView = false;    // doesn't work
                instance.$el.data("settings").listView = false;     // doesn't work either
            });
            $el.on("click", ".popup.settings li.list", function(){
                // do stuff...

                //settings.listView = true;     // doesn't work
                instance.$el.data("settings").listView = true;     // doesn't work either
            });


        },

        showSettings: function (el){
            var settings = this.$el.data("settings");   // doesn't 

            var props = {
                classes: "settings",
                isList: settings.listView
            };

            // do more stuff...
        },

    }

    $.fn.pluginName = function(options){
        return this.each(function() {
            var config = {
                listView: false
            }

            methods._init($(this), options, config);

        });
    };

    $.fn.pluginName.defaults = {
        fullMobileQuery: "48em",   
        verticalScrollOffset: 30    
    };

}(jQuery));
```